# react context methods to update state are not available via props in cosumer

Tags: react-native, react-context

i am trying use react context for data sharing between components. first trying to create a context and update it.

the methods i include as part of provider aren't available in my consumer, but the objects/variables are available.., weird.
i have made a state to be updated and a couple of methods to perform the update. but the methods are not accessible in the consumer.here is the sample code repo: https://codesandbox.io/s/k990k14k7

can someone look into it and help me?

Comment: the method are there.. a) they don't get serialized in `stringify` and b) you're not calling the function in your onClick handler `<button onClick={() => context.someAct3()}> ` <-missing parens

Comment: thanks, but here: https://codesandbox.io/s/rm09krr824 i am able to print the function, what might be the difference? can you please comment on it for my understanding?

Comment: the difference is that the function `stringify` strips out functions